# Array Index Out of Bounds Error Java

Tags: java, arrays

So while I run this method I keep getting the array index out of bounds error. I am familiar with this error, but I don't see why it is occurring in this instance. Here is the code:

```
public void setFrequencies() {

        List<Word> dupeWordList;
        dupeWordList = wordList;
        dupeWordList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
        Collections.sort(dupeWordList);

        for(int i = 0; i < dupeWordList.size(); i++) {
            int count = 1;
            Word tempWord = dupeWordList.get(i);
            tempWord.setFrequency(count);
            Word nextWord = dupeWordList.get(dupeWordList.size() - 1);
            if(i+1 < dupeWordList.size() - 1) {
                nextWord = dupeWordList.get(i+1);
            }
            while(tempWord.getValue() == nextWord.getValue()) {
                count++;
                i++;
                tempWord.setFrequency(count);
                for(int e = 0; e < count - 1; e++) {
                    Word middleWord = new Word();
                    if((i-count+1)+1+e < dupeWordList.size() - 1) {
                        middleWord = dupeWordList.get((i-count+1)+1+e);
                    }
                    middleWord.setFrequency(count);
                }
                if(i+1 < dupeWordList.size() - 1) {
                    nextWord = dupeWordList.get(i+1);
                } else {
                    nextWord.setValue("the");
                }
            }
        }
        List<Word> reSortedList = wordList;
        Word fillWord = new Word();
        fillWord.setFrequency(0);
        fillWord.setValue(null);
        Collections.fill(reSortedList, fillWord);
        for(int i = 0; i < dupeWordList.size(); i++) {
            Word word = dupeWordList.get(i);
            int wordOrder = word.getOrigOrder();
            reSortedList.set(wordOrder, word);
        }

        setWordList(reSortedList);
    }
```

The line which has the issue is the line that contains `nextWord = dupeWordList.get(i+1)` in the if statement. However if you look above, you can see that I have the exact same statement above, yet it does not produce an error. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the code line by line?

Comment: From your code I get the impression that you think dupeWordList is a copy of wordList (it is not)?

Comment: I was trying to make it a duplicate, yes.

Comment: The line at which this error is occurring is not clear: you have `nextWord = dupeWordList.get(i+1);` within a conditional block multiple times. Show us where it occurs with a comment. Also, as sstan suggested, you should step through the code with a debugger and look at what's happening with `i` line by line—at some point as you step, do you make a `get` call that would exceed the index bounds? (You can set a breakpoint condition if you have some idea which iteration the issue occurs on—or you could temporarily print `i` to see how far you get in iteration.)

Comment: post your stack trace logcat..

Comment: If you want to copy the list, you want something more like: `dupeWordList = new ArrayList<>(wordList);`  Otherwise, your changes are all on the same list.

Comment: another thing that I see is that nextWord.setValue("the") is string so in the while loop you should compare with the .equals() method instead of "=="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you are running into some kind of inifinite loop where your condition is `while(tempWord.getValue() == nextWord.getValue()) {`.  Maybe both values can stay stuck at `"the"`?

If that were to happen, then the variable `i` would increment to the point where it would go past `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and would start having negative values.

If that were to happen, then the condition `if(i+1 < dupeWordList.size() - 1) {` will become true, but your value for `i` will be invalid for your list and will throw the out of bounds exception.

(BTW, you really should use `equals()` to compare strings, not `==`)

Comment: Figured it out, it was an issue of it getting hung on "the". I changed that line to break and went from there error free. And with the == instead of .equals(), I just realized that. I'm used to c# so thats where I get that from.

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing index i both in for loop line and inside the while loop. That sounds to me a bit "no-no". Do you know for sure what you are doing there ? I have a gut feeling that you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I do know that in that code, i needs to be changing according to what I have in there, but I may be taking the wrong approach in doing so...? Would that be causing the error or was that just something that looks out of the sorts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to this piece of code?

```
if(i+1 < dupeWordList.size() - 1) {
        nextWord = dupeWordList.get(i+1);
}
```

So, `dupeWordList.size()-1` is the last index location you can reference. You are referencing `i+1`, which is less than the last index (because of the `if` statement condition). So, you are trying to `get` a word that is before the last word.

According to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)), you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   index >= size())

Since your if statement guarantees that the index is not >= size(), then the only possibility must be that index < 0.